# Why is validation performed only after?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a form with a validation of name and email.
The test is performed well. The problem is that it only absorbs one action after another.
Explain: If you wrote in the text box of the name and filled in a valid email, the button still does not work. Only with the next click of the button does he discover this and activate the button. (Even if the next action is to delete the email or add an invalid character it will confirm.)

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      EmailError: true,
      emailHelperText: "",
      nameHelperText: "",
      nameError: false,
      errorCheck: true,
    };
  }

  onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length > 2) {
      this.setState({ nameHelperText: "", nameError: false });
      this.ifErrors();
    } else {
      this.setState({ nameHelperText: "נא למלא שם", nameError: true });
      this.ifErrors();
    }
  }
  validateEmail(e) {
    var email = e.target.value;

    if (validator.isEmail(email)) {
      this.setState({ EmailError: false, emailHelperText: "" });
      this.ifErrors();
    } else {
      this.setState({ EmailError: true, emailHelperText: "נא למלא מייל תקין" });
      this.ifErrors();
    }
  }

  ifErrors = () => {
    console.log(
      "nameError",
      !this.state.nameError,
      "EmailError",
      !this.state.EmailError
    );
    console.log(!this.state.nameError && !this.state.EmailError)
    if (!this.state.nameError && !this.state.EmailError) {
      this.setState({ errorCheck: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorCheck: true });
    }
  };
```

```
  <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                helperText={this.state.nameHelperText}
                onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                error={this.state.nameError}
                required
                id="outlined-required"
                label="שם מלא"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <TextField
                helperText={this.state.emailHelperText}
                onChange={this.validateEmail.bind(this)}
                error={this.state.EmailError}
                required
                id="outlined-required"
                label="דואר אלקטרוני"
              />
```